# Swing mouse drag identification problem?

Tags: java, swing, mouse

How do I identify mouse dragged in downward direction? Suppose I dragged down, I need code such as this:

```
int graphy = e.getY();
System.out.println("this is y axises " + graphy);
_graph._verticalScroll.setValue(graphy + _graph._headerWidth
    + _graph._verticalScroll.getValue());
```

What code should i put when mouse dragged down?

Comment: Have you read [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Comment: @trashgod i saw that link but im did not  get answer specific code to identify as mouse dragged  down direction

Comment: Please post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) showing what you've tried. Your current example has no context.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [MouseAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) and implement [`mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html#mouseMoved%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29).

You have to check the coodrinates using `e.getPoint()` or `e.getY()` and compare with the previous event to get the direction.

You can detect if the mouse is dragged upwards or downwards with code similar to this:

```
if(e.getY() > previousY) {
  // drags downwards
} else if (e.getY() < preiousY) {
  // drags upwards
}
previousY = e.getY();
```

Comment: @jones exactly in moused dragged function i want to identify wether mouse dragged upward or downward

Comment: @Ganesh: You need to show more of your code. And you need to write what error you get or why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ganesh: You can not start with `previousY = e.getY();` then it can't work.

Comment: if(e.getY() > previousY) {
   
 int  graphy = e.getY();
 System.out.println("this is y axises "+graphy);
      _graph._verticalScroll.setValue(graphy+_graph._headerWidth+ _graph._verticalScroll.getValue());

      // drags downwards
} else if (e.getY() < previousY) {
  int  graphy = e.getY();
     
      _graph._verticalScroll.setValue(graphy+_graph._headerWidth+ _graph._verticalScroll.getValue());

      // drags upwards
    }

Comment: @jones befor that i declare previousY = e.getY()

Comment: @Ganesh: What error do you get? It's better if you post the code in your question.

Comment: @jones control is not giving inside that condition means condition not satissified

Comment: @Ganesh: Does the control have a mouslistener? you need to provide more information.

Comment: @jones It is going inside mouse dragged but not in this condition if(e.getY() > previousY)

Comment: @Ganesh: print the value for `e.getY()` and `previousY`

Comment: @jones Its working  fine i used same method for identify left and right it causes problem